# How to find if users exist in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Web SDK and know methods to check whether a child in a collection exists or not. However I can't find a concise example checking the existence of a user, without trying to sign him/her in.

```
export class Email extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { email: '' }
  }

  checkEmail () {
    const { email } = this.state
    FirebaseApp.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, uuid.v4())
    .then((User) => Actions.Password({ User }))
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      console.log('firebase', {error})
      this.setState({error})
      // ...
    })
    // Actions.password()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ ...styles.onboarding, backgroundColor: 'purple' }}>
        <View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 3, borderColor: 'black', padding: 10 }}>
          <TextInput ref='email'
            style={styles.input}
            keyboardType='email-address'
            placeholder='Your email'
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email: email.toLowerCase()})} />
        </View>
        {!this.state.error ? null
          : <Text>
            {this.state.error.message}
          </Text>
        }
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkEmail()} style={{ ...styles.button, margin: 20, borderColor: 'black' }}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Do you have any piece of code we could reuse?

Comment: Have you got the user id of the user you want to query?

Comment: No, I want to check existance before user creation

Comment: Are the user id's in your database automatically generated by OAuth or are they picked/customized by users?

Comment: Show your JSON (as text, no screenshot) and what you've already tried.

Comment: User id's should be plain email, as I understand from joining firebase development recently. This is what I have tried so fire, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, and because it complies with my app security policy and setup, I created an email collection indexed precisely by ids.

```
firebase.ref(`emails/${user.email}`).set(true)
```